# Fluid grid with aligned columns (HTML, CSS)

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a grid of equally sized boxes that always take up the full width of the container while staying vertically aligned. One way to do it is to calculate width and margins based on the container width, but in a way it feels clumsy to do it like that. It turned out to be hard with a flexbox solution as well to both expand the boxes to take up the full width and keeping the last row aligned with the others even if it has less elements in it.

I also made a small JSFiddle to start from if anyone feels like playing around. [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/3de6noet/12/)
[image: grid examples]

`'`

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [mcve]

Answer (score 2):

I'd try something with columns instead of flexbox...

```css
.container {
    width:100%;
  column-count:999;
  column-width:7em;
  column-gap: 0.1em;
}

.box {
  -webkit-column-break-inside: avoid; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
  page-break-inside: avoid; /* Firefox */
  break-inside: avoid; /* IE 10+ */
  height: 3em;
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 0.1em;
  background-color: lightgray;
}
```

```html
<div id="containerId" class="container">
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
    <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Interesting solution, but now the rows are not aligned and boxes are cut at the start/end of columns.

Comment: Hmmm... I'm not seeing that here, in fact the preview in the fiddle above looks exactly like your third case looking here in Chrome 65 (MacOS). The break-inside CSS directive is supposed to prevent it from splitting the divs, and therefore keeping the column alignment intact. What browser are you trying this in?

Comment: I added webkit and moz prefixes to the box rules... Maybe see if that helps.

Comment: I still have the same issue where the boxes are cut at the bottom of a column to then continue on the next column

Comment: @Gearbox, what browser/OS are you using?

Comment: I tried again with prefixing based on https://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/b/break-inside/

Comment: I tried playing around with that solution a bit more and it seems as if page-break still does not work. (firefox quantum). One other thing I noticed that I didn't think of adding is that the order of the boxes matter, which now is vertical instead of horizontal.

Answer (score 1):

What's about [this solution](https://jsfiddle.net/25zj1t95/4/)?

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}
.box {
  height: 3em;
  width: 7em;
  margin: 0.1em;
  background-color: lightgray;
  flex: 0 0 auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
  <div class="box"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: The issue with that solution is the empty space at the side, to make a clean looking grid the boxes should stretch so that the extra space is filled as well. Your answer matches the middle case in the picture in the question.

Comment: @Gearbox - just change the width on `.box` to a percentage and it will go full width.

Comment: But with a set percentage the boxes will get too small on smaller screens instead of having fewer boxes per row (while still using the full row)

Comment: What about your solution?